# Finding the area not by integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, area

> *Original problem.* Find the area under $y= \sqrt{x}$ in the range $\left [ 0, 1 \right ]$

My friend, she wants to use total area instead of calculating the integeral. So I tried something:

Dividing the area by $n$ parts with each part is $\Delta x= \frac{1}{n}$.

The part $k$ is $\left [ \left ( k- 1 \right )\frac{1}{n}, \frac{k}{n} \right ]$, we calculate the total area by formula:

$$S_{n}= \sum_{k= 1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}}= \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\sum_{k= 1}^{n}k^{1/2}$$

How should I do next ?? Thank you....

Comment: I mean, ultimately you're going to end up taking a limit as $n \to \infty$ and all, and this all would just be a roundabout way to take the integral.

Comment: The sum is harmonic, but she seems to not know anything about it, sob sob

Comment: It's easier if you see it as the area of the square minus the area of the region $\{(x,y)\,:\, y\le x^2\land 0\le y\le 1\}$.

Comment: For $\int_0^1 x^adx$, this is equivalent to $f(a)+f(1/a)=1$ where $f(x)=1/(1+x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the partition points more carefully. They need not be equidistant, just near to each other. Choose an $N\gg1$ and put
$$x_k:={k^2\over N^2}\qquad(0\leq k\leq N)\ .$$
You then have
$$\sqrt{x_k}={k\over N},\qquad x_k-x_{k-1}={2k-1\over N^2}<{2\over N}\ .$$
This leads to the Riemann sums
$$R_N:=\sum_{k=1}^N f(x_k)\,(x_k-x_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^N{k\over N}\,{2k-1\over N^2}=\ldots\quad.$$
It is easy to compute the last sum explicitly, and you will then see that $$\lim_{N\to\infty}R_N={2\over3}=\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\>dx\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Find the $S$ area of $y=x^2$ in $[0,1]$. The wanted area is $1-S$

[image]

Comment: Copy that , sir